# Magento : Filter categories using custom attribute

Tags: php, magento

I have an custom attribute in category called show_in_sidebar i want to filter all those categories whose show_in_sidebar attr is set to one

I have tried :

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->addAttributeToSelect('show_in_sidebar','1');
print_r($categories);
```

AND

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('show_in_sidebar','1');
    print_r($categories);
```

But both are not giving anything.... how can i do this please help...

Comment: see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/209818/#t280827

Comment: @RachelGallen Thx for your reply  i have tried this...
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('show_in_sidebar');
 foreach ($collection as $Category){
    echo $Category->getName()."<br/>";
 }
But did't worked...

Comment: @RachelGallen after a bit of modification your hits worked for me please post your comment as Answer i will accept and upvote... Thx a lot...

Comment: thanks :) upvotes are always greatly appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `getCollection()` before filtering of selecting category attribute I hope.

Check out,

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('show_in_sidebar')->load();
```

Comment: Thx for reply this didn't worked $Collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('show_in_sidebar')->load();